# Search for a particular function in all packages

Tags: python, package

In each application there are some libraries that provide functions with the same names. For example "imread()" can be found in OpenCV, Scikit-image, as well as Matplotlib libreries.

Is it possible to search and list functions with same names in all installed packages?

Comment: Du you want all functions names that have duplicates, or just "tell me if this has duplicates" ?

Comment: @Artog the later one: Does it has a duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` from the directory of your project (if you're using a virtual environment), or in your home directory (assuming installed packages are in `~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`):

```
grep -R "def imread"
```

output:

```
venv/Lib/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py:def imread(fname, format=None):
venv/Lib/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py:def imread(fname, format=None):
venv/Lib/site-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.py:def imread(name, flatten=False, mode=None):
venv/Lib/site-packages/scipy/ndimage/io.py:def imread(fname, flatten=False, mode=None):
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. In Windows and with Jupyter how we can get this list?

Comment: When you open a commandline (`cmd`) and type `grep` and hit enter key, do you get an error?

Comment: I'm familiar with Unix commands, but I must to work in a Windows environment.

Comment: Ah ok, as long as grep is installed on your system, you can run `!grep -R "def imread"` in Jupyter and it will give you the output in the answer

Comment: There is no installed Unix-like shell on the system.

Comment: Are you allowed to install it? Go to https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/grep/2.5.4/grep-2.5.4-bin.zip/download, download the zip file, extract the `exe` files in `./bin` into `c:\windows` or just in your project directory, then run the command

Comment: I deleted my answer. It doesn't really work as i thought. While you *can* list modules with either `iter_modules` or `walk_packages`, you don't get the module object, and thus cant run `dir`on them. You need to either loop over all py files in the paths you get from iterating and reading the contents or you need to load every module you can find and then iterating over all loaded modules. Neither is particularly good solutions and both are filled with errors and problems.

Comment: If you only want to check among loaded modules, that's a whole other story and I can help with that.

Comment: Thank you for comments. I'm agree with you and I think the only workaround that works in all systems is to load modules and then search among them. So, I would be grateful if you could send an answer about how to check among loaded modules. @Artog

Answer (score 1):

As per our conversation. This script is limited to checking for a specific function in all loaded modules. The result will be a dictionary where the keys are the functions and the value is a set of all modules where you can find the same function.

More than one key means multiple definitions of the same name.

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
import types

def find_functions_by(function_name):
    definitions = defaultdict(set)
    for _, module in sys.modules.items():
        if fn in dir(module):
            definitions[getattr(module, fn)].add(module)
    return definitions


# Just testing:
import skimage
import matplotlib

fn = "imread"
[print("Found function:", key, list(map(lambda x: x.__name__, modules))) for key, modules in find_functions_by(fn).items()]
```

On my computer, it gives the output:

```
Found function: <function imread at 0x0DE8D8A0> ['skimage.io', 'skimage.io._io', 'skimage.data']
Found function: <function imread at 0x0DE621E0> ['skimage.external.tifffile.tifffile', 'skimage.external.tifffile']
Found function: <function imread at 0x0E283ED0> ['skimage.io._plugins.imageio_plugin', 'imageio.core.functions', 'imageio', 'imageio.plugins.lytro']
Found function: <function imread at 0x0EA56DF8> ['matplotlib.image', 'skimage.io._plugins.matplotlib_plugin']
```